# PHP Multudimensional Array foreach

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

Using PHP and MySQL, I have generated an array called `$response`.

A `var_dump` of `$response` can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/faS9Snsw).

```
array(2) {
  ["OperationRequest"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["HTTPHeaders"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["Name"]=>
          string(9) "UserAgent"
          ["Value"]=>
          string(14) "ApaiIO [2.1.0]"
        }
      }
    }
    ["RequestId"]=>
    string(36) "f53f381e-efb3-4fef-8e39-4f732b4b463e"
    ["Arguments"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Argument"]=>
      array(11) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Name"]=>
            string(14) "AWSAccessKeyId"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(20) "KEY"
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Name"]=>
            string(12) "AssociateTag"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(11) "TAG"
          }
        }
        [2]=>
        array(1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Name"]=>
            string(6) "IdType"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(4) "ISBN"
          }
        }
        [3]=>
        array(1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Name"]=>
            string(6) "ItemId"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(38) "0751538310,9780141382067,9781305341141"
          }
        }
        [4]=>
        array(1) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(2) {
            ["Name"]=>
            string(9) "Operation"
            ["Value"]=>
            string(10) "ItemLookup"
          }
        }.......so on
```

A `json_encode` of the array can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/SXH5eWFw) (as requested in a comment).

I'd like to select the `Title` from these two items. From what I can see this is located at;

```
Items > Item > ItemAttributes > Author
```

So, using a `foreach` loop I have tried the following;

```
foreach ($response as $item) {
    echo $item['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']; // line 2
}
```

However this returns the following error;

> Message: Undefined index: Items. Line Number: 2

Where am I going wrong and what must I change in my code in order to achieve the desired result?

Also, any advice on how to 'read' multidimensional arrays would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: youn need to do like this:- `echo $item['OperationRequest']['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']; `

Comment: @johnny_s Can you share the `json` of the above array?

Comment: @johnny_s `echo json_encode($response);`

Comment: @johnny_s ```echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);```

Comment: @johnny_s, your array keys must exist. What I see is that you use array keys like 'Items', 'item', and that they don't exist in the actual array (var_dumped). That's why you get this error,...

Comment: @johnny_s I hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, it will help you out. You were are iterating on the wrong key that's why you were not getting desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/792073)`from json provide by OP in question`

```
foreach($array["Items"]["Item"] as $key => $value)
{
    print_r($value["ItemAttributes"]["Title"]);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Output:**

`Panic
Panic
Captain Flinn and the Pirate Dinosaurs: Missing Treasure! (Captain Flinn)`

**For getting unique titles:**

```
foreach(json_decode($json,true)["Items"]["Item"] as $key => $value)
{
    $result[]=$value["ItemAttributes"]["Title"];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
print_r(array_unique($result));
```

Answer (score 1):

@Also, any advice on how to 'read' multidimensional arrays would be greatly appreciated.

Post your encoded json string to

http://json.parser.online.fr

"+" and "-" button at the right panel should help you read it easily.

```
//Check Items is not empty
if( !isset($response["Items"]["Item"]) || empty($response["Items"]["Item"]) )
    throw New Exception("Empty Item");

foreach($response["Items"]["Item"] as $item){
    $title = $item['ItemAttributes']['Title']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link to http://json.parser.online.fr @Parfait - both very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You should debug as:

```
foreach ($response as $key => $item) {
    if(isset($item['Items'])){ //Check Items index defined
        echo $item['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title'];
    }else{
        var_dump($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of that exactly? That produces `string(16) "OperationRequest" string(5) "Items"`. Thanks

Comment: Because your array defined by keys, You have to input exactly keys as path for access child array. If array with key not exist, php will warning is: "Undefined index"
With "OperationRequest" and "Items" key, It hasn't child array $item['Items'] => error

You can add this script for debug each key:
var_dump($key);
die;